# Facebook Like Button gets cropped at the bottom

Tags: facebook-like

I am trying to align the Facebook like button along with the G+1 and Tweet's one, but I can't figure out what is wrong. The facebook button gets cropped at the bottom. 
You can see my issue at the top of the website [Mobilise IT](http://www.mobiliseit.com)

Here's my code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>

<script>        (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=438999086139815";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="social">
    <!-- +1 -->
    <div class="plusone">
    <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
    <g:plusone size="medium" annotation="none"></g:plusone>
    <!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
</div>
    <!-- end +1 -->
    <!-- twitter -->
<div class="twitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-via="dominoc">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>    
</div>
<!-- end twitter -->
<!-- like -->
<div style="vertical-align: top;padding-top:2px;width:46px;overflow:hidden;" class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Mobilise-IT/166950133340282" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
<!-- end like -->
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.social-icon
{
    background-image:url(images/social-icons.png);
    margin-left:-2px;
    padding-left:25px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.twitter
{
     background-position:left 2px;
 }
 .facebook
 {
     background-position:left -14px;
     margin-right:5px;
 }
 .linkedin
 {
     background-position:left -29px;
 }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

PS: I can't upload an image yet, need more rep , when i can i will so you can have a better view of my issue.

Comment: I've found a lot of sites with the same issue an some others that they don't have it... It's really weird... Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could align the facebook button by using: in your CSS

```
.fb-like{ padding: 0 0 4px 0 !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks Alastair this did the job! :)